# how to remove shoes from an image of a character and leave barefoot in photoshop cs6 or cs2?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

for example I have a image of a character displayed in photoshop and I see only the shoes and from there I will want to remove to show the feet 
will tool history brush do this?
[image: example image with shoes]

Comment: how to configure the history brush tool or modify to leave only bare feet? obs I'm not good at painting or drawing on the feet, I wanted a more automatic way for this

Comment: That is *not* what the history brush does. No tool in any application anywhere will do what you are asking. It's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to **paint** in the feet.

Images are flat. They don't "cover up" things. If you remove the shoes.. she will have no feet. You will have to draw/paint in the feet.

Although TV shows such as CSI would have people believe it's possible to "remove something as see what's behind it" in an image. That is **not** how **reality** works.

Comment: How do I paint barefoot in the image above from this shoes? some other more realistic brush tool for this? Thanks for help!